# error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string_view' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Log(std::string_view message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* text = "Test";
    Log(text);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I am getting that error and `#include <string>` is included at the start. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/k4ypY-) What compiler, and standard version are you using? Also, `#include<string_view>`.

Comment: @cigien I am using **ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)**. Btw I added `#include<string_view>` and now it works. Thank you very much! But I still curious why it is not working. in Cherno's youtube video his code was working without adding `#include<string_view>`. You can check from his video. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO68JEgoPeg&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=80)

Comment: It's not guaranteed to work if you don't include the necessary headers. In practice, compilers will include other headers, so if the needed headers are included, it appears to work. Note that the link I made in the comment doesn't have `<string_view>`, so it's wrong, but it compiles.

Comment: i understand. Thanks for clean explanation :) @cigien

Comment: duplicate is a different case, but the answer is the same

Comment: `-std=c++17` as compiler option will do the trick

Comment: @gkhaos As i said I am using std=c++17 already. After adding `<string_view>` it solved.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Its not duplicate. Its not about adding `#include <string>` to my code. Read the question and the solution. Actually i didnt get my real answer, @cigien just solved my problem not the answer. Follow the comments pls.

Comment: I did read the comments and you say that in a video exact same code compiled wihtout error and the duplicate explains how that can happen, though I agree that its not the best dupe for the question

Comment: what do you mean with "just solved my problem not the answer" ? isnt adding the include the answer to your question?

Comment: It compiles for me without problem on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others already mentioned - std::string_view is defined in the standard header "string_view", which must be included - otherwise string_view is not defined.

Because you include some headers like "string" and "iostream" which have some connection to std::string_view it is clear that they do at least some forward_declarations.

In some implementations string_view might be already included in other system headers.
For example std::string_view could be implemented/defined in the header "string" and the header "string_view" could just include "string".

But in general this is an implementation detail of the library implementation. To be able to use std::string_view, it is required to include that header.